# Check if last X characters of a field are numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In fact there are 2 questions, 2 queries:

- I'd need to find out is a numeric that beginning with `'541'` is `18 chars` long
  In fact there is a space right after SO: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when....'541'....15RandomNumbers in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).....an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.`
- Second: Check if last 18 chars of a string are numeric (maybe after a trim right)

That's it,

Comment: Try `SUBSTRING` and `ISNUMERIC`

Comment: @Paddy Post this as answer and I will happily upvote, just because there's nothing more to say.

Comment: @tombom: maybe for you there is nothing more to say...? Very sorry but I don't see code yet that defines that the last 18chars of the field are numeric ? isnumeric is not something I don't know

Comment: @Arion: I changed the question a little: it's just a random text: a form on a website in fact. But, you can forget the first part of my question, the second is more important. Thx

Comment: @laurens It's the combination of `SUBSTRING` and `ISNUMERIC`! "but I don't see code yet", pfff. This is not a "do my work for me" site. Use your own brain if you want to become good at something!

Comment: @laurens you might also use `RIGHT()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"find out is a numeric that beginning with '541' is 18 chars long"

```
( text_col NOT LIKE '541%' OR LEN(text_col) = 18 )
```

"Check if last 18 chars of a string are numeric (maybe after a trim right)"

```
   ( RTRIM(text_col) LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' )
```

Comment: Thank you, in fact this should be more 'robust' than ISNUMERIC

Answer (score 1):

Some data to start you off

```
declare @tmp table (value nvarchar(30))
insert @tmp values ('ABC123456789123456789'),('ABC12345678912345678A'),('ABC123456789123456D78')
```

Look at `RIGHT` and `ISNUMERIC`

```
SELECT t.value, ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(t.value,18)+'.0e0') as [IsNumeric]
FROM @tmp t
```

Gives:

```
value                          IsNumeric
------------------------------ -----------
ABC123456789123456789          1
ABC12345678912345678A          0
ABC123456789123456D78          0
```

***Edit:*** I've amended my answer as per the feedback from `Damien_The_Unbeliever` and it has fixed the problem he raises

Comment: Sorry, I meant, I would upvote you for not posting actual code

Comment: Thank you! In fact, not so hard... but everyone his specialties right

Comment: This is the answer to your second question, you'll need to do something similar for your first - look at Google for SQL `LEFT`

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is rather flaky. For instance, change your second value to `'ABC123456789123456D78'`, and it will return a 1.

Comment: @laurens http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ <-- this is my business. Belgians........

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Hmm, you're right, might have to start my own SO question about that!

Comment: @Paddy - there are plenty of questions already on here that discuss it in either the question or the answers. Long story short - it answers a question nobody ever actually wants to ask ("Can this string be converted to any of the numeric types?" rather than the more sensible "Can this string be converted to an int?" (or replace "int" with any specific numeric type))

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever -Very true, I've edited my answer with the suggestion from http://stackoverflow.com/a/5988983/1016183.

Comment: @laurens Don't know if you missed the edit but the addition of `.0e0` (as per my previous comment). Fixes the issue raised by `Damien_The_Unbeliver`. This answer may perform better than the other due to the `LIKE` clause.