# isnumeric with bug?

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnumeric

Execute command bellow in SQl Server 2014.

```
   select ISNUMERIC('1E234') -- return 1
   select ISNUMERIC('1E2341') -- return 0
```

I expect that the first select returns 0

My solution:

```
     -- if return 0 is numeric 
     select PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%','1E234') 
     select PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%','1E2341') 
     select PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%','102341')
```

Best regards!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: isnumeric supports `float` and `real`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms173773.aspx    +/- 1e308, basically. `e2341` is outside the allowable range.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988939/isnumeric07213e71-true

Comment: Thanks @MarcB for explanation about exponecial values in float and real types.

Answer (score 2):

1e234 is **actually a number**. It's the scientific notation, meaning: **1.00×10<sup>234</sup>**. (throw that in a calculator!)
Another example to emphasize, would be **3.1e24** which is equal to **3.1×10<sup>24</sup>**.

This is why you get that result: it's correct (up to a certain limit).

```
3.1E24 => 3,100,000,000,000,000,000,000,904

 1E234 =>   1,000,000,000,000,000,256,144,
          240,016,312,560,912,656,840,512,
          968,136,864,872,232,424,776,040,
          744,208,304,800,656,032,440,648,
          488,920,616,296,544,576,976,448,
          056,376,040,432,472,424,840,856,
          440,904,776,056,632,368,528,312,
          448,144,432,344,224,424,808,952,
          160,472,416,864,520,520,320,112,
          296,192,360,016,000,088,968

1E2341 => too big to calculate!!!
```

The problem with your solution, is that sometimes `e` is used for number notations in computer science too, so the e-notation must be taken into account as a working number.